# How to download a PDF via MS Power Automate Desktop "Download from web" flow

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I have a simple MS Power Automate Flow with this "Download from web" flow under HTTP. Now I have a SSRS Report server link which downloads a report(PDF) as soon as you paste and hit enter in any web browser. When I put the same link to the "Download from web" it downloads "ReportViewer.aspx" but not a PDF. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use Launch browser?

```
WebAutomation.LaunchChrome.LaunchChrome Url: $'''https''' WindowState: WebAutomation.BrowserWindowState.Normal ClearCache: False ClearCookies: False WaitForPageToLoadTimeout: 60 Timeout: 60 BrowserInstance=> Browser
```